# Any News from the Oracle Entity Framework

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

More than half a year ago, Oracle issued a [Statement of Direction](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/oracle-entity-framework-sod-130214.pdf) announcing that they will support the .NET entity framework with ODP.NET and promising a beta version by the end of last year.

I haven't heared anything since then. Are these plans still valid? And when can we expect a beta version or the final release?

Comment: why don't you try to use NH that has well estabilished Oracle Drivers ?

Comment: @Felice: So does Java. Neither one, however, actually answers his (legitimate) question.

Comment: @Craig difficult to answer, and personally I would'nt go in production with EF+Oracke, at least today.

Comment: @Felice: The purpose of this site is for asking questions which might be difficult, no? You're entitled to your opinion, but posting it on random questions isn't really appropriate here. His question deserves an answer (even if the answer turns out to be "no, they're not valid anymore"), not a thread-jacking.

Comment: @Craig, I agree this is the reason I used a comment :) In comment can't we express suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beta is due very very soon!
Check this site often for the announcement:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html

Christian Shay
Oracle

Comment: Looks like the beta is finally out as of Feb 10.

Answer (score 0):

There are some third-party solutions such as http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle. If you're looking for something official from Oracle, then AFAIK it's in Beta.

EDIT: The official Beta from Oracle has been released today, look here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html

Comment: We're in an evaulation. Devart's product is already in the evaluation. But if Oracle releases a solution soon, we'd like to include it as well.

Answer (score 0):

On 28 Dec 2011, they've put a release version of "Oracle Data Access Components" that supports Entity Framework. You can download it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

I have downloaded & installed them and tried on a very minimal program. It works and it seems to work fast. (Much faster than DevArt, "dotConnect For Oracle" tool, I'm sorry to say)